# how do i put backcolor on a selectListItem

Tags: asp.net-mvc, selectlistitem

i have an asp.net mvc page and i want to have a dropdown list with different background color [like this page](http://pietschsoft.com/post/2004/09/20/Color-the-background-of-items-in-a-Dropdown-box-in-your-HTML-pages.aspx)

i have the following code to display a dropdown list

```
<label>Data Source: </label><% = Html.DropDownList("DataSource", Model.CalendarDataSources, new { @id = "calendarDSDropdown", @class = "calendarDSDropdown" })%>
```

in my viewmodel i have:

```
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> CalendarDataSources;
```

which i am populating on the server.  I want to add a different backlog to each SelectListItem but i can't see how to do that as select list item only has **Name, Id, Selected** properties

is this possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately the built-in `DropDownList` helper doesn't allow you to set the `style` attribute on the generated `option` tags. You will have to roll your own helper to achieve this.

As an alternative you could use jQuery to set the color:

```
$(function() {
    $('select#DataSource option').each(function() {
        var option = $(this);
        option.css(
            'background-color', 
            someFunctionThatMapsTheOptionValueToAColor(option.val())
        );
    });
});
```

Comment: the issue with that is that i want a different color for each item (which i know on the server)

Comment: Yes but you also know on the server the value for each item. So you could generate dynamically a mapping function between the value and the color which you could use in my jQuery example. If not you will have to implement your own html helper.

Comment: true, i think the custom helper seems a little more straight forward but thanks for both suggestions